# Wordpress: Email script for a custom form?

Tags: php, email, plugins, wordpress

Is there any plugin or script to process a simple custom form and send it away?

I have a very simple webshop of two items made by hardcoded HTML and now I just want to post the form to a php-script which sends it away to two reciepnts (myself and the customer).

I've been trying to setup a simple script using the mail() function but it doesnt work and I can't get the error message.. tried the ini_set('display_errors...) etc. But I don't want to mess around with this now. I remember doing it couple of years ago and it just too much time to start fiddling around with server settings etc etc..

Any ideas of a out of the box working solution?

Cheers

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter/

Comment: Wordpress has a built in wp_mail function. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying the mail() function but it's not actually sending the email and you aren't getting any errors? I use a library called PHPMailer to send emails:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

It sounds like you want the email to be pre-formatted with all of your form elements. You might have to write your own email format but maybe there's something out there for you?

Comment: Thanks, seems like a fair solution.